# How do I connect an XML comment to an API help page?

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api, documentation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am working on a project that requires documentation on an API Help page. The page is already created, and it is ready for information to be inserted. But I have some issues:

1. I am very new to this, so I am having some issues navigating through the project.
2. I want to reference XML comments that are directly within the Controller files, like this:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Get all the number of help desk tickets by their current priorities
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>


   [ActionName("GetCurrentPriority")]
   public TicketPriorities GetTicketsByCurrentPriority()
   {...
   ```

The HTTP route code in the WebApiConfig.cs file looks like this:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

However, I don't know how to post the comment on the web help page. I have seen many examples where a parameter ID is used, but there appears to be no ID, and I don't know how to find the parameter ID or make it, since the Help page shows all but the ID. For example, should I create an `XMLDocument.xml` file and put all the comments in there?

Answer (score 3):

You have this line of code?

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

Also don't forget to tick "XML documentation file" in the Project Properties -> Build. Set the path to `App_Data\XmlDocument.xml`.

You may also want to suppress warning CS1591 since there will be plenty of classes (such as in the Help generating code) which are `public` but do not need documentation added to them.

See this documentation for more details: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: I have that line uncommented, but I am unsure of where to go from there? Do the XML comments go into the XmlDocument.xml file?

Comment: what you mean exactly? u have to tell vs to generate the xml for you.. Under Output, check XML documentation file. In the edit box, type “App_Data/XmlDocument.xml”. from there document you code as usual..